# Update array with value of checkbox checked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array as below

```
var selected = [];

$scope.listA = [
  {
    name : "Sample 1"
  },
  {
    name : "Sample 2"
  },
  {
    name : "Sample 3"
  }
];
```

The input html element is

```
<div ng-repeat="label in checkMode()">
    <input type="checkbox" checked> {{ label.name }}</input>
</div>
```

How can i get an array of selected values based on the checkboxes checked?
For example, I want to get the below selected values

```
var selected = ["sample 1","sample 3"];
```

Also be able to update the array.

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244427/angular-js-inputradio-doesnt-work/36244545#36244545

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" checked ng-init="WRITE_YOUR_LOGIC"> {{ label.name }}</input>`

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple lightweight directive that does this

http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy..

add one click function in checkbox, Hope this should work...ref link...[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kayivacife/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div ng-repeat="label in checkMode()">
   <input type="checkbox" checked ng-click="toggleSelection(label.name)> {{ label.name }}</input>
</div>
$scope.listA = {
    name : "Sample 1"
  },
  {
    name : "Sample 2"
  },
  {
    name : "Sample 3"
  }
];

$scope.selected=[];

  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(selected) {
    var idx = $scope.selected.indexOf(selected);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.selected.push(fruitName);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-checked` to achieve this like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = ['Sample 2'];

  $scope.listA = [{
    name: "Sample 1"
  }, {
    name: "Sample 2"
  }, {
    name: "Sample 3"
  }];

  $scope.toggleChecked = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(item.name);
    if (index == -1) {
      $scope.selected.push(item.name);
    } else {
      $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-repeat="label in listA">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(label.name) > -1" ng-click="toggleChecked(label)">{{ label.name }}
    </div>
    <pre>{{selected}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```