# Multiple radio button groups within angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a html table I am using with ng-repeat to show display data from an array

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="foo in bars">
    <td>{{foo.Group}}</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="foo.Group" ng-model="foo.Field1"/></td>
</tr>
```

The rows in array bars have a group field. I want the only on radio button to be selected per group.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244427/angular-js-inputradio-doesnt-work/36244545#36244545

Answer (score -1):

It appears you're just missing the braces on the name attribute to properly assign the group to it.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="foo in bars">
    <td>{{foo.Group}}</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="{{foo.Group}}" ng-model="foo.Field1"/></td>
</tr>
```