# How to do radio buttons in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface, radio-button

This is my code. When I submit switchColors, the server returns undefined for it. How is this wrong?

Also how should I initiate $scope.swichColors in my controller? Currently I have $scope.switchColors = '';

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.switchColors" value = "yes" >Yes</input>
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type= "radio" ng-model = "$parent.switchColors" value = "no" >No</input>
</label>
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244427/angular-js-inputradio-doesnt-work/36244545#36244545

Answer (score 1):

Try using ng-value instead of value

```
 <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.switchColors" ng-value = "yes" >Yes</input>
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type= "radio" ng-model = "$parent.switchColors" ng-value = "no" >No</input>
    </label>
```

Comment: I think I am initiating switchColors incorrectly in my controller, right now I am just doing '$scope.switchColors = '';'

Comment: should I be doing something different? Because now I cannot select the buttons

Comment: also in the docs here: they used value instead of ng-value. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D